# Which Pancharatra text has controversial statements on Vedas?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, sri-vaishnava, pancharatra

It is known that Adi Shankara had presented the view that Pancharatra is not in accordance with the Vedas in his commentaries.

I want to know how many such verses are there in the agama which is directly or indirectly blaming the vedas?

For instance the following [statement](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34221.htm):

> Moreover, manifold contradictions are met with in the Bhâgavata
>   system, with reference to the assumption of qualities and their
>   bearers. Eminence of knowledge and ruling capacity, strength, valour,
>   and glory are enumerated as qualities, and then they are in some other
>   place spoken of as Selfs, holy Vâsudevas, and so on.--Moreover, we
>   meet with passages contradictory of the Veda. The following passage,
>   for instance, blames the Veda, **'Not having found the highest bliss in
>   the Vedas Sândilya. studied this sâstra.'-**-For this reason also the
>   Bhâgavata doctrine cannot be accepted.