# What are the rules mentioned in vedas for people?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, yajur-veda, sama-veda

Samhitas do not mention dharma but [rta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%B9%9Ata) what acts really supports [rta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%B9%9Ata) according to vedic samhitas daily life, manners etc.

**Note:—please mention from rigveda and samaveda after that yajurveda and these three only. Please mention from rigveda and samaveda in pletny verses.**

Comment: Whats is "rta"..could you please be kind enough to elaborate..

Comment: @YDS msny people do not know it but it is basic concept of rigveda at the roots is rta dharma and karma came accordingly gods are aloso not controler of rta as adityas are his chariot usha its root varuna friend etc. — https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ṛta

Comment: Ohh better u mention that in ur question..at first glance i thought it's either acronym or abbreviation.. :)

Comment: Rta or Rtam is the truth-law-in movement for the Gods.. They are born in it and they follow it.. but they are not for us.. i don't think we can get rules in Rig and Yajur Vedas.. Also in Samaveda there's nothing new..everything is already present in the Rig Veda.. Some rules can be found in Atharva Veda though.. See my answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22295/4732

Comment: I have got already in a **awgp** book divine message of vedas they are in parts containing selected verses of all 4 vedas it is great book. btw @rickross do you want to say rta is not for us????

Comment: @Fiercelord: Good question