# How does the Karnataka's Lingayat community worship differently compared to other Shiva Linga devotees?

Tags: shiva, worship, culture, other-religions, shiva-lingam

The community name is derived from the "Linga", & hence it should be part of Hinduism.
However, recently Karnataka government proposed [special religious status](http://www.firstpost.com/politics/karnataka-govt-gives-lingayats-separate-religious-status-splits-community-siddaramaiah-risks-blowback-ahead-of-polls-4396567.html) to the Lingayat community.

Is the worship form of this community any different than the other devotees of "Shiva Linga"?

Comment: Do they belong to a different religion? BTW i know that they do the Ista Linga worship which is quite different from traditional ritualistic worship.

Comment: @Rickross, yes henceforth it might be a separate religion. See [Wikipedia: Lingayatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingayatism#Separate_religious_identity_(21st_century)).

Comment: also see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26203/13287