# Which work of Basavanna contains this statement?

Tags: identification-request

From [this](http://sivastotravalli.blogspot.in/2010/04/philosophy-behind-my-articlea-short.html) site:

> Basavanna says:
>
> I will pour insects in the mouth of one who identifies, Hari (Vishnu) with Hara (Siva)
>
> Hari has ten births and death,
>
> Brahma has countless births and deaths,
>
> Is Hara subject to such births and deaths?

Which work of Basavanna contains this statement?

Note: Please avoid fuelling controversy to this post.